ECONNRESET error socket hang up when creating tasks with nodejs cloud-run with fallback true
Our server had a problem with Deadline exceeded which appeared frequently, I looked for a solution to solve the problem and found an issue from 2020 and the google team pointed out a solution to use:
const client = new CloudTasksClient({ fallback: true });

This solved the problem for me, however it created a new problem when trying to create so many tasks (some users data creates 14000 tasks). This problem didn't appear when the deadline exceeded was appearing. Like the cloud run server could work for a week before starting to throw deadline exceeded.
Now the new problem which I am trying to understand is:
FetchError: request to https://cloudtasks.googleapis.com/v2/projects/dev/locations/europe-west3/queues/XAPI/tasks?$alt=json%3Benum-encoding=int failed, reason: socket hang up"
 at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1501:11)
  at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:517:28)
at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:525:9)
 at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:529:35)
  at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1400:12)
  at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {

  type: 'system',
 errno: 'ECONNRESET',
 code: 'ECONNRESET'

this is the time of the error: 2024-07-30 09:40:08.513
then the server starts to create tasks, this run created approx 4500 tasks and this is the time of the last task created: 2024-07-30 09:40:10.139
this is the code where I create the google tasks:
const { CloudTasksClient } = require("@google-cloud/tasks").v2;
const client = new CloudTasksClient({ fallback: true });

const createTask = async (url: string, payload: TaskPayload): Promise<void> => {
  const parent = client.queuePath(project, location, queue);
  const task: protos.google.cloud.tasks.v2.ITask = {
    httpRequest: {
      httpMethod: "POST",
      url,
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(payload)),
    },
  };

  try {
    const [response] = await client.createTask({ parent, task });
    console.log(`Created task ${response.name}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error creating task:", error);
    throw error;
  }
};

and this is where i use the function:
const BATCH_SIZE = 250;

export const processBatches = async (
  tasks: Promise<void>[],
  batchSize: number = BATCH_SIZE
) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < tasks.length; i += batchSize) {
    const batch = tasks.slice(i, i + batchSize);
    try {
      await Promise.all(batch);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error processing batch:", error);
    }
  }
};

 try {
    const data = payload.data as unknown as Body[];
    const user = payload.user as User;
    const userRefId = user.reference_id;
    let tasks = [];

    for (const bodyData of data) {
      const startTime = bodyData.metadata.start_time;
      const endTime = bodyData.metadata.end_time;
      const collectionId = generateCollectionId(startTime, endTime);

      const collectionsData = generateBodyCollections(bodyData);

      for (const [collectionName, collectionData] of Object.entries(
        collectionsData
      )) {
        const filteredData = removeNullValues(collectionData);
        if (!areAllValuesNullOrEmpty(filteredData)) {
          tasks.push(
            createTask(uploadUrl, {
              userRefId,
              collectionName,
              docId: collectionId,
              data: filteredData,
            })
          );
        }
      }
    }

    await processBatches(tasks);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error processing body data:", error); //this is where the error comes up.
  }

This is the function that handle the google tasks:
const functionConfig: HttpsOptions = {
  region: "europe-west3",
  memory: "4GiB",
  cpu: 2,
  timeoutSeconds: 500,
  concurrency: 80,
  minInstances: 0,
  maxInstances: 50,
};

export const uploadToFirestore = onRequest(
  functionConfig,
  async (request, response) => {
    const { userRefId, collectionName, docId, data } = request.body;
    try {
      const docRef = firestore
        .collection("patients")
        .doc(userRefId)
        .collection(collectionName)
        .doc(docId);
      await docRef.set(data, { merge: true });

      response.status(200).send("Data uploaded successfully");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error uploading data to Firestore:", error);
      response.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
    }
  }
);


this is the queue details:
Location
europe-west3
Rate limits
Max rate
500/s
Max concurrent
5000
Max burst size
100
Retry parameters
Max attempts
100
Min interval
0.100s
Max interval
3600s
Max doublings
16
Max retry duration
Unlimited
As i mentioned this error started to appear when i used fallback true, If i remember right when i looked at the tasks yesterday I saw an error with permission denied which didn't appear before when everything was working (sometimes if the deadline exceeded didn't appear).
Any insights or suggestions to resolve this ECONNRESET error would be greatly appreciated.
Feel free to adjust any specific details or code snippets as needed.
I tried to reduce the batch size to 250 and got this error:
FetchError: request to https://cloudtasks.googleapis.com/v2/projects/dev/locations/europe-west3/queues/XAPI/tasks?$alt=json%3Benum-encoding=int failed, reason: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established"

Or it maybe because i changed the version of CloudTasksClient from "@google-cloud/tasks";@google-cloud/tasks.v2.

I had an issue with the same behavior. It was due to ipv6. I had to make strict the use of ipv4.
